# SQL Server 2008 Express Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I am having trouble getting the following query to work properly:

```
SELECT  
   tblEmployees.iEmployeeNum AS ID, tblEmployees.tLastName AS SURNAME, tblEmployees.tFirstName AS NAME,
   pInt.dtEventReal AS 'ENTRANCE', pIes.dtEventReal AS 'EXIT'
FROM 
   tblEmployees
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
       dtEventReal,idEmpNum 
   FROM 
       tblEvents 
   WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Entrance%' 
       AND CAST(tblEvents.dtEventReal AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2014-07-07' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-07-08' AS DATE) 
   ) AS pInt ON pInt.idEmpNum = tblEmployees.iEmployeeNum
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
       dtEventReal, idEmpNum 
    FROM 
       tblEvents 
    WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Exit%' 
       AND CAST(tblEvents.dtEventReal AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2014-07-07' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-07-08' AS DATE) 
   ) AS pIes ON pIes.idEmpNum = tblEmployees.iEmployeeNum
WHERE 
   iEmployeeNum = 265 
   AND (CAST(pInt.dtEventReal AS DATE) = CAST(pIes.dtEventReal AS DATE) 
        OR (DATEPART(hh, pInt.dtEventReal) >= 18 
            AND CAST(pInt.dtEventReal AS DATE date) = CAST(pIes.dtEventReal-1 AS DATE)))
```

The result that I get are:

```
ID  SURNAME   NAME        ENTRANCE                  EXIT
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 07:56:08.000 2014-07-07 10:21:34.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 15:12:17.000 2014-07-07 10:21:34.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 07:56:08.000 2014-07-07 16:47:31.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 15:12:17.000 2014-07-07 16:47:31.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 07:56:34.000 2014-07-08 10:05:39.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 14:32:53.000 2014-07-08 10:05:39.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 07:56:34.000 2014-07-08 16:46:35.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 14:32:53.000 2014-07-08 16:46:35.000
```

What I am looking for is:

```
ID  NAME    SURNAME      ENTRANCE                  EXIT
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 07:56:08.000 2014-07-07 10:21:34.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-07 15:12:17.000 2014-07-07 16:47:31.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 07:56:34.000 2014-07-08 10:05:39.000
265 LAST    FIRST   2014-07-08 14:32:53.000 2014-07-08 16:46:35.000
```

L.E. 1 - the last condition is there

```
OR
(datepart(hh,pInt.dtEventReal)>=18 and cast(pInt.dtEventReal as date)=cast(pIes.dtEventReal-1 as date)))
```

because we have people that work night shifts and finish the next morning.

L.E. 2 -

the events are being added to the database automatically by a software that gets the events from a controller:

```
IdAutoEvents tDesc          dtEventReal           tLastName tFirstName   iEmployeeNum
    312503  Main_Entrance   2014-07-18 07:24:33.000 SURNAME NAME            265
    312742  Main_Exit   2014-07-18 10:31:23.000 SURNAME NAME            265
```

L.E 3 - Final version based on mxix answer:

```
SELECT  
    E.iEmployeeNum ID, 
    E.tLastName SURNAME, 
    E.tFirstName NAME,
    pInt.dtEventReal AS 'ENTRANCE', 
    pIes.dtEventReal AS 'EXIT',
    pInt.tDesc AS 'Entrance Location', 
    pIes.tDesc AS 'Exit Location'
FROM tblEmployees E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT 
        dtEventReal,
        idEmpNum,
                tDesc
    FROM tblEvents 
    WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Entrance%' AND 
       CONVERT(DATE,tblEvents.dtEventReal) BETWEEN cast('2014-07-07' as date) AND cast('2014-07-12' as date)
) pInt ON 
    pInt.idEmpNum = E.iEmployeeNum
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
        TOP 1
        dtEventReal, 
        idEmpNum,
                tDesc
    FROM tblEvents Ev
    WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Exit%' AND
       Ev.idEmpNum = pInt.idEmpNum and
       pInt.dtEventReal < Ev.dtEventReal
    ORDER BY
        dtEventReal ASC
   ) AS pIes
WHERE 
        E.IdDepartment in (2,11)
        ORDER BY E.tLastName ASC, E.tFirstName, pInt.dtEventReal
```

Comment: Oops, I misread a couple lines. Sorry about that. Could you explain the pattern that you're looking for? How do you get to the second result set from the first?

Comment: I added some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
   DECLARE 
    @start DATE = '2014-07-07',
    @end DATE = '2014-07-07',
    @user_id int = 265;

SELECT  
   E.iEmployeeNum ID, 
   E.tLastName SURNAME, 
   E.tFirstName NAME,
   pInt.dtEventReal AS 'ENTRANCE', 
   pIes.dtEventReal AS 'EXIT'
FROM tblEmployees E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT 
        dtEventReal,
        idEmpNum 
    FROM tblEvents 
    WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Entrance%' AND 
       CONVERT(DATE,tblEvents.dtEventReal) BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pInt ON 
    pInt.idEmpNum = E.iEmployeeNum
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
        TOP 1
        dtEventReal, 
        idEmpNum 
    FROM tblEvents Ev
    WHERE
       tDesc LIKE '%Exit%' AND
       Ev.idEmpNum = pInt.idEmpNum and
       pInt.dtEventReal > Ev.dtEventReal
    ORDER BY
        dt_EventReal ASC
   ) AS pIes
WHERE 
    E.iEmployeeNum = @user_id
```

Comment: With a few modifications  it worked like a charm, I posted below the final version. For some reason, declare it didn't work so I switched back to cast for the start and end date. Also, the was a typo, pInt.dtEventReal > Ev.dtEventReal should've been pInt.dtEventReal < Ev.dtEventReal. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, instead of answering my own question, I added the final version in the initial question.